# Showing "Invalid payment method." in woocommerce while going to pay for cart item's

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment

While paying for cart items an error message always displaying that "Invalid payment method.". I set shipping method but still getting same error. I am new in WordPress please suggest me what to do?

Comment: Visit this link: http://sangkrit.net/fix-woocommerce-invalid-shippingpayment-method-error/

Comment: You can try putting some logs and check if there is some issue with the function calls or any such things https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: my shipping method is not updating from admin end.Any idea?

Comment: updating from admin means ?

Comment: In Woocommerce there is a section named Shipping. From where I am trying to add Pincode and saving shipping zone. but it is not working.

If you have woocomerce setup then u can check from this link 
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=shipping&zone_id=1

Answer (score 3):

Go to Woocommerce Setting->Payment(tab) you will find list of payment method ,You have to enable and setup one of the payment method from the list